# Why is my palindrome function not working?

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

For some reason my palindrome function is not working, I'd love some help on it:

***Code***

```
int Pal(char *s, int a, int b)
{
    if (a>= b)
        return 1;

    if (s[a] != s[b])
        return 0;

    return Pal(s, ++a , --b);
} 

int main()
{
    char *s = "civic";

    if (Pal(s , 1, strlen(s)))
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
}
```

It keeps printing No, and I'm clueless to why this is happening.

Comment: Finding a palindrome is not a problem that requires recursivity. There's no hierarchy involved, nor is there a stack collection.

Comment: Don't forget that array indexes are *zero* based. That means an array of 5 elements have indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive).

Comment: The first element of `char *s = "civic";` is `s[0]`, the last one (not counting the `'\0'`) is `s[4]`.

Comment: Try `Pal(s , 0 ,strlen(s)-1 )`

Comment: problem solved, Thank you all!

Comment: `s` should be `char const *` both in `main()` and and as the parameter of `Pal()`. `int main()` should be `int main(void)` if this is supposed to be `C` and not `C++`.

Comment: in the recursive call, you can just write `return Pal(s, a+1, b-1);`, you don't need to change `a` and `b` itself

Comment: @sturcotte06 Very few problems *requires* recursion, but very many are *suitable* to be solved with recursion. I don't see any problem using recursion for this.

Comment: @Broman  `unsigned int sum(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { if (b == 0) return a; return sum(++a, --b); }` ;)

Comment: @Calvin If one of the questions solved your problem, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're starting point for the function is incorrect:

```
if (Pal(s , 1 ,strlen(s) ))
```

Arrays in C and C++ have a starting index of 0.  So you're actually starting at the second character and ending at the null terminating byte at the end of the string.

Use a value of 1 less for both the start and the end:

```
if (Pal(s, 0, strlen(s)-1 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
bool isPalindrome(char *str, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
  if ( startIndex >= endIndex)
    return true;

  if (str[startIndex] != str[endIndex])
    return false;

  return isPalindrome(str, ++startIndex , --endIndex);
} 
int main()
{
  char *str = "civic";

  if (isPalindrome(str , 0, strlen(str)-1))
    printf("YES\n");
  else
    printf("No\n");
}
```

Some points to consider

1. character arrays are used for string in C.
2. Arrays in C have a **starting index** of **0**
3. Arrays in C **endIndex** is **size - 1**.

Other Improvements possible, though they are very minor:

1. Have **returnType** of recursive function as boolean (lesser memory).
2. Have more clearer names for data members.

Example:

```
char string[]={'c,'i','v','i','c'};  //size=5
// indexes:     0  1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

The character at position `strlen(s)` **is not the last character in the string**, but the `\0` character that marks its end.  If you want to check against the last one, change

```
    if (Pal(s , 1, strlen(s)))
```

by

```
    if (Pal(s , 0, strlen(s)-1))
```

(but be careful to check first that the string `s` has at least one character, or the expression will be wrong ---you cannot check for palindrome an empty string---)

String indices go from `0` to one character less than `strlen(s)`.